# Proteção de string em C++ usando MySQL Connector

Tags: mysql, c++, segurança, engenharia-reversa

Eu fiz um programinha pra checar meu banco de dados, e queria ver se as strings eram protegidas (do usuário senha e o banco de dados) e no caso não são.
Eu descompilei o programa usando o IDA PRO e descobri que as *strings* e informações não são protegidas.

Código em Questão

```
con = driver->connect("localhost", "root", "aaasd");
```

Imagem do código descompilado.

[image: Programa descompilado]

Tem como proteger essas *strings*?
O *connector* tem alguma função para proteção de strings (pois não achei)?

E o que vocês da comunidade me recomendariam para proteger meu programa (já olhei alguns ofuscadores de .NET)?

Me lembro que no C# ele protegia essas strings.

O programa é para distribuição e digamos que a base de consumidores dele não é agradável, e muito provavelmente vão tentar descompilar o programa...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Então não tem solução (dessa forma), se as pessoas são capazes de decompilar (e sempre pode cair na mão de quem pode) elas são capazes de descriptografar algo que precisa de uma chave e um algoritmo rodando na aplicação. Mas elas nem se darão ao trabalho de verificar isso, só ver onde descriptografar e pegar a senha de forma plana.

A única solução é não colocar a senha disponível em lugar algum acessível pelas pessoas. Ou deve usar um acesso integrado com o sistema operacional, ou integrado com o banco de dados (alguém vai ter que digitar uma senha), ou tem que deixar a aplicação em local que as pessoas não acessam, ou ainda deve fazer uma aplicação servidora acessível sem senha e ela acessa o banco de dados (claro que ela terá que controlar o acesso por conta própria).

Não existe solução segura para arquitetura errada.

Comment: o negocio é que o programa qualquer um pode baixar sem restrição... eu não acho um problema poderem acessar o código mas sim a senha do banco de dados. em c# na biblioteca do MySQL ele escondia essa string no caso de descompilação, não tem um método parecido em c++?

Comment: Não é o C# que provê a segurança, é o sistema operacional, ele só facilita. Então é oque eu falei, tem como, mas tem que delegar para o sistema operacional fazer isto. Mas ainda assim não quer dizer que está 100% seguro já que tudo está no computador da pessoa, ela pode até passar por cima do sistema operacional.

Comment: é verdade tem como mesmo mas isso ai passa do limite pra mim saca? tipo na minha cabeça se for pra decompilar o programa (que ja é pouco conhecido a tecnica) vale a pena (pensando na cabeça dos maluco) mas se for pra passar por cima do sistema operacional pra descompilar não.

Comment: você tem alguma referencia dessa função que é chamada no MySQL, e se eu posso usa-la?

Comment: É possível criptografar, mas não resolve o problema. O que existe e não sei o quanto é eficaz é a criptografia completa do próprio conector, mas só está disponível na versão paga.